# Can I use an NSAttributedString for textView.text in JSQMessagesViewController cell?

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a need to use an NSAttributedString to set the `cell.textView.attributedText` instead of using an NSString to set `cell.textView.text`. This doesn't seem currently possible. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops. Spoke too quickly. I see if I just set this in:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I'll get what I want!